# Cannot copy encoded ABI Remix to verify

Tags: ethereum, solidity, abi, remix

i deployed a smart contract that had 7 constructor arguments, but i left 2 empty on purpose. Only now i cannot copy the encoded ABI because i left 2 fields empty on Remix IDE. I tried getting the encoded data from https://abi.hashex.org/ but that did not work sadly.

My constructor arguments are:

```
_maxSupply: 10000
_publicMintCost: 2000000000000000
_maxMintAmountPerWallet: 15
_maxFreeMintAmountPerWallet: 1
_teamSupply: 20
_hiddenMetadataUri: *EMPTY*
_uriPrefix: *EMPTY*
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

UPDATE: i was saved by this article: https://dev.to/jamiescript/how-to-deploy-and-verify-a-smart-contract-from-remix-42gl

The encoded input data could be found in the input data of the contract creation tx, i could copy the last trailing 0 from the input data and boom verified. never knew you could find the encoded input data there. saved me a few bucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your constructor arguments. The ABI-encoded information I got is as follows.

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000271000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000071afd498d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002222200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022222000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks for helping did not work though sadly.

Comment: Your code probably was correct, but i just saw after verifying i accidentally put a "," in the_hiddenMetadataUri field when deploying. Tyvm